# Bigquery - remove duplicates of certain columns, but not all

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have two tables I am left joining together. The first tables has transnational level detail, causing the key I join to the second table to duplicate. When I left join the second table, the measure "company_spend" is highly inflated.

I need a way to keep only a single value of the duplicated data, and my thought was to run a distinct function on only those columns, but I am not seeing that Bigquery supports distinct functions on only a few columns, but not all.

```sql
 SELECT UPPER(cwnextt.Current_Contract_Number)         AS Current_Contract_Number,
       UPPER(cwnextt.Replacement_Contract_Number)     AS Replacement_Contract_Number,
       UPPER(cwnextt.Current_Contract_Name)           AS Current_Contract_Name,
       UPPER(cwnextt.Supplier_Top_Parent_Entity_Code) AS Supplier_Top_Parent_Entity_Code,
       UPPER(cwnextt.Supplier_Top_Parent_Name)        AS Supplier_Top_Parent_Name,
       UPPER(cwnextt.company_Entity_Code)             AS company_Entity_Code,
       UPPER(cwnextt.Facility_Name)                   AS Facility_Name,
       smart.company_Spend                            AS companySpend
  FROM `test_etl_field.contracts_with_member_entity_codes_test_view_2` cwnextt 
  --this table is what is causing the below table to duplicate,
  --but I need all of this data AS well in its current format. 
LEFT JOIN `test.trans_analysis` tsa 
    ON TRIM(UPPER(cwnextt.company_entity_code)) = TRIM(UPPER(tsa.company_entity_code)) 
       AND TRIM(UPPER(cwnextt.Supplier_Top_Parent_Entity_Code)) = TRIM(UPPER(tsa.manufacturer_top_parent_entity_code)) 
       AND TRIM(UPPER(cwnextt.Current_Contract_Name)) = TRIM(UPPER(tsa.contract_category)) 
       AND cwnextt.spend_period_yyyyqmm = tsa.spend_period_yyyyqmm 
       --this table contains "company_spend" which is now duplicated 
LEFT JOIN `test_etl_field.ecr_smart_data` smart 
    ON smart.company_entity_code = cwnextt.company_entity_code 
       AND (smart.contract_number = cwnextt.current_contract_number 
    OR smart.contract_number = cwnextt.replacement_contract_number) 
       AND smart.month_key = cwnextt.spend_period_yyyyqmm
```

If something can be created that will keep company_spend from duplicating on the second left join, that is what I am after.

Comment: What do you mean highly inflated? Could you edit your question and add current and desired table output?

Comment: Thanks for the comment. 
In my case, I am not quite understanding how the group by will work, as that will aggregate the already duplicated data. 

For example - Table 1 key is 44. left join to table 2 on key 44, but table 2 has 44 twice. Therefore, the row has duplicated due to other columns which are needed in the table. I left join to table 3 which has my costs on key 44. Costs are $10, but show as $20 because 44 is listed twice. 

Make sense?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure to understand all the details of your problem but here's a fact from [BigQuery doc](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/query-syntax#select-modifiers) :

> **`SELECT DISTINCT`**
>
> A `SELECT DISTINCT` statement discards duplicate rows
>   and returns only the remaining rows.

You can't apply `DISTINCT` on specific columns because it doesn't make sense. Let's say you have 4 columns and call `DISTINCT` on 3 columns, what is SQL supposed to do with the last one ?
You must tell SQL which value to keep for the remaining column and `GROUP BY` is the right solution here.

So if you want to:

1. **Remove a column that has been duplicated** : Just adjust your `SELECT` to get only the columns you want
2. **Remove lines that have the same value in specific columns** : I would suggest a `GROUP BY` on the targeted column and taking the aggregation you want (first, avg, sum or whatever) for the remaining ones.
3. **Remove the value from a row if another row has the same**  : You may not want to do that. A row has to keep its value and you won't get it back. Besides, same problem, which row do you want to keep ?

Hope this helps ! Feel free to give clarification on your problem if you want more specific answers.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. 
In my case, I am not quite understanding how the group by will work, as that will aggregate the already duplicated data. 

For example - Table 1 key is 44. left join to table 2 on key 44, but table 2 has 44 twice. Therefore, the row has duplicated due to other columns which are needed in the table. I left join to table 3 which has my costs on key 44. Costs are $10, but show as $20 because 44 is listed twice. 

Make sense?

Comment: @Bava you work with rows, so if a joined table has twice, the row is showing up twice. You either display the data eg: firstname twice, or you can choose to choose min/max/aggregated value if you want to combine into one single row

Comment: @Pentium10 How do I aggregate to a single row when the row is joined on a duplicated key?

Answer (score 0):

While I couldn't resolve this issue in SQL, I used Tableau via a FIXED LOD to aggregate the data passed duplicates so the end user could visualize the output with accuracy. Not ideal, but the SQL route wasn't make sense.